# Restrict Viewing Page in MediaWiki

Tags: permissions, mediawiki

Is it possible to restrict the viewing of a page in MediaWiki (1.24.1) to only authenticated users that belong to a certain group?

Answer (score 1):

If it is a special page (extension page), you can easily do that. for main namespace, this is what mediawiki has to say about page level permissions.

> If you need per-page or partial page access restrictions, you are
>   advised to install an appropriate content management package.
>   MediaWiki was not written to provide per-page access restrictions, and
>   almost all hacks or patches promising to add them will likely have
>   flaws somewhere, which could lead to exposure of confidential data. We
>   are not responsible for anything being leaked, leading to loss of
>   funds or one's job.